# Trying to import a variable from file but console say's file doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, electron

when i try to import a variable from a JavaScript file into another one, my console return's an error that the file doesn't exist. Here is my file that is causing the problem my console log, and the file i want to import the variable in.

**Button.js**

```
var MONEY = 0;

const element = document.getElementById("moneyButton");

element.addEventListener("click", function moneyHandle() {
    MONEY++
    document.getElementById("moneycount").innerHTML = `You have: ` + MONEY + `$`;
});

module.exports = { MONEY };
```

**Clicker.js**

```
const { MONEY } = require('../misc/button')

const element = document.getElementById("clicker")

if (MONEY === 15) {
    console.log('User has enetered stage.')
    element.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

**Console Log**
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HODUJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your code, all the logic is being conducted on the Electron render side.

Whilst this is not a problem, it does introduce some issues such as how to regularly check for when `MONEY === 15`. To do this, you would need to use a function such as `setInterval` which will slow down this particular render process.

As an alternative, keeping count of `MONEY` in your main process via the use of [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) would be the recommended way.

That said, as your question is based around render side [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) functionality, we will stay in the render thread only and not introduce you to IPC.

- Use of `module.exports` and `require` is CommonJS syntax, which is used by NodeJS (server-side).
- Use of `import` and `export` is ECMAScript (ES module) syntax, which is used in browser-side Javascript.

As your Javascript is render process (browser-side) Javascript, we must use the `import` and `export` statements.

For additional explanation from the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) website:

> ### Import
>
> The static `import` declaration is used to import read-only live bindings which are [exported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) by another module. The imported bindings are called *live bindings* because they are updated by the module that exported the binding, but cannot be re-assigned by the importing module.
>
> In order to use the `import` declaration in a source file, the file must be interpreted by the runtime as a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). In HTML, this is done by adding `type="module"` to the [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag. Modules are automatically interpreted in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

> ### Export
>
> The `export` declaration is used to export values from a JavaScript module. Exported values can then be imported into other programs with the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) declaration or [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). The value of an imported binding is subject to change in the module that exports it — when a module updates the value of a binding that it exports, the update will be visible in its imported value.
>
> In order to use the `export` declaration in a source file, the file must be interpreted by the runtime as a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). In HTML, this is done by adding `type="module"` to the [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag, or by being imported by another module. Modules are automatically interpreted in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

---

**NOTE:** The below minimum reproducible example does not take into account your current directory structure. For simplicity, I have coded the below using a flat directory structure as folder hierarchy is not causing your current issue.

---

`index.html` (render process)

To get your current code working, we need to add the below lines of code to your `index.html` file.

```html
<script type="module" src="button.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="clicker.js"></script>
```

This allows the Javascript runtime to interpret these files as [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="moneyButton" value="Show me the money">

        <p id="moneyCount">&nbsp;</p>

        <hr>

        <div id="clicker" style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 1em; opacity: 0;">Clicker</div>
    </body>

    <script type="module" src="button.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="clicker.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

`button.js` (render process)

Next, we need to change `module.exports = { MONEY };` to `export {MONEY};`

```js
let money = 0;

document.getElementById("moneyButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
    money++;
    document.getElementById("moneyCount").innerHTML = 'You have: $' + money;
});

export {money};
```

---

`clicker.js` (render process)

Lastly, to import the live binding `MONEY`, let's change `const { MONEY } = require('button')` to `import {money} from './button.js';`.

```js
import {money} from './button.js';

// setInterval used to regularly check for changes in the live binding variable 'money'
setInterval(() => {
    if (money >= 15) {
        console.log('User has entered stage.')
        document.getElementById("clicker").style.opacity = "1";
    }
}, 250); // Check every 250ms
```

Comment: That but me into the right area but now im getting another error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module```

Comment: Can you post the whole error message into a comment so we can see the issue. It would be interesting to know what file is generating the error + the contents of the file.

Comment: [This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSDlt.png)

Comment: I have fixed my last error and im getting a new error ``Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
`` This is the screenshot of it also. [New error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptMQ9.png)

Comment: Your latest error sounds like a folder hierarchy issue. Is `button.js` trying to load another file on it's first line?

Comment: No it isn't trying to load another file.

Comment: The `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` means that the file can't be found. This only occurs when the file doesn't exist, it's in a different folder or the file name is different to that requested.

Comment: Don't forget to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) this answer if it helped you.